# Could not load type 'Sitecore.Reflection.INexusDataApiEx' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel,

Tags: reflection, sitecore, sitecore8

I am getting this runtime error and can not find anything on the internet around this reference. 'Sitecore.Reflection.INexusDataApiEx'

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Error message]

Comment: can you compare your sitecore.kernel.dll with same dll from a Sitecore clean solution. The clean solution must be the same like your version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors like this are usually seen after upgrading or some mismatch in dependencies in your solution. As 'Climber' mentioned, get the zip for a clean version of Sitecore, exactly matching the version you are using (not just "8.1" but also the correct minor update-x version). Verify that your Sitecore.Kernel.dll is the same as the one in the clean version. And verify the other dll's as well (so actually verify the entire bin folder - it should be the same exactly apart from the dll's that came from your own code).

If you have dependencies to Sitecore dll's in your solution (Nuget or otherwise), also verify that they refer to the correct version or you might have the same problem again after a deploy.

Comment: Thanks very much! you were correct. the original instance of sitecore was a slightly lower version of 8.1 which did not have some of the methods being referenced. Solution was to get original sitecore.kernal and dll and xml and not copy over the new version during the publish by setting the Copy to local to "FALSE"